# How to do this in XSLT without incrementing variables? (Tweaking Xalan to create a global XSLT iterator. Do I have other options?)

Tags: xslt, xerces, xalan

I'm trying to think functional, in XSLT terms, as much as possible, but in this case, I really don't see how to do it without tweaking. I have roughly this data structure:

```
<transactions>
  <trx>
    <text>abc</text>
    <text>def</text>

    <detail>
      <text>xxx</text>
      <text>yyy</text>
      <text>zzz</text>
    </detail>
  </trx>
</transactions>
```

Which I roughly want to flatten into this form

```
<row>abc</row>
<row>def</row>
<row>xxx</row>
<row>yyy</row>
<row>zzz</row>
```

But the tricky thing is: I want to create chunks of 40 text-rows and transactions mustn't be split across chunks. I.e. if my current chunk already has 38 rows, the above transaction would have to go into the next chunk. The current chunk would need to be filled with two empty rows to complete the 40:

```
<row/>
<row/>
```

In imperative/procedural programming, it's very easy. Just create a global iterator variable counting to multiples of 40, and insert empty rows if needed ([I have provided an answer showing how to tweak XSLT/Xalan to allow for such variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964846/tweaking-xalan-to-create-a-global-xslt-iterator-do-i-have-other-options#7964979)). But how to do it with XSLT? N.B: I'm afraid recursion is not possible considering the size of data I'm processing... But maybe I'm wrong on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the complete XML data structure as you need in Java. Then, do the simple iteration in XSL over prepared XML.

You might save a lot of effort and provide a maintainable solution.

Comment: This of course, is an alternative solution. But I'd really like to know how to do it properly in XSLT...

Answer (score 3):

**I. Here is an XSLT 1.0 solution** (the XSLT 2.0 solution is much easier):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pChunkSize" select="8"/>
 <xsl:param name="vChunkSize" select="$pChunkSize+1"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vSheet" select="document('')"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfEmptyChunk">
  <xsl:for-each select=
   "($vSheet//node())[not(position() > $pChunkSize)]">
    <row/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vEmptyChunk" select=
  "ext:node-set($vrtfEmptyChunk)/*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfDummy">
  <delete/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vDummy" select="ext:node-set($vrtfDummy)/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <chunks>
   <xsl:call-template name="fillChunks">
    <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="trx"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pCurChunk" select="$vDummy"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </chunks>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="fillChunks">
  <xsl:param name="pNodes"/>
  <xsl:param name="pCurChunk"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not($pNodes)">
     <chunk>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="rename" select="$pCurChunk[self::text]"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select=
        "$vEmptyChunk[not(position() > $vChunkSize - count($pCurChunk))]"/>
     </chunk>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="vAvailable" select=
          "$vChunkSize - count($pCurChunk)"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vcurNode" select="$pNodes[1]"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vTrans" select="$vcurNode//text"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vNumNewNodes" select="count($vTrans)"/>

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($vNumNewNodes > $vAvailable)">
         <xsl:variable name="vNewChunk"
              select="$pCurChunk | $vTrans"/>

         <xsl:call-template name="fillChunks">
           <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="$pNodes[position() > 1]"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="pCurChunk" select="$vNewChunk"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
         <chunk>
          <xsl:apply-templates mode="rename" select="$pCurChunk[self::text]"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select=
            "$vEmptyChunk[not(position() > $vAvailable)]"/>
         </chunk>

         <xsl:call-template name="fillChunks">
          <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="$pNodes"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pCurChunk" select="$vDummy"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text" mode="rename">
  <row>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </row>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (based on the provided one, but with three `trx`elements):

```
<transactions>
  <trx>
    <text>abc</text>
    <text>def</text>

    <detail>
      <text>xxx</text>
      <text>yyy</text>
      <text>zzz</text>
    </detail>
  </trx>
  <trx>
    <text>abc2</text>
    <text>def2</text>
  </trx>
  <trx>
    <text>abc3</text>
    <text>def3</text>

    <detail>
      <text>xxx3</text>
      <text>yyy3</text>
      <text>zzz3</text>
    </detail>
  </trx>
</transactions>
```

**the wanted, correct result (two chunks with size 8) is produced**:

```
<chunks>
   <chunk>
      <row>abc</row>
      <row>def</row>
      <row>xxx</row>
      <row>yyy</row>
      <row>zzz</row>
      <row>abc2</row>
      <row>def2</row>
      <row/>
   </chunk>
   <chunk>
      <row>abc3</row>
      <row>def3</row>
      <row>xxx3</row>
      <row>yyy3</row>
      <row>zzz3</row>
      <row/>
      <row/>
      <row/>
   </chunk>
</chunks>
```

**Do note**:

1. The first two transactions' `text` elements total number is 7 and they fit in one 8-place chunk.
2. The third transaction has 5 `text` elements and doesn't fit in the remaining space of the first chunk -- it is put in a new chunk.

**II. XSLT 2.0 Solution (using [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net))**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
xmlns:dvc-foldl-func="dvc-foldl-func"
exclude-result-prefixes="f dvc-foldl-func"
>

   <xsl:import href="../f/func-dvc-foldl.xsl"/>
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:param name="pChunkSize" select="8"/>

   <dvc-foldl-func:dvc-foldl-func/>

   <xsl:variable name="vPadding">
    <row/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:variable name="vFoldlFun" select="document('')/*/dvc-foldl-func:*[1]"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

      <xsl:variable name="vpaddingChunk" select=
       "for $i in 1 to $pChunkSize
         return ' '
       "/>

      <xsl:variable name="vfoldlResult" select=
          "f:foldl($vFoldlFun, (), /*/trx),
           $vpaddingChunk
          "/>
      <xsl:variable name="vresultCount"
           select="count($vfoldlResult)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vFinalResult"
       select="subsequence($vfoldlResult, 1,
                           $vresultCount - $vresultCount mod $pChunkSize
                           )"/>
      <result>
       <xsl:for-each select="$vFinalResult">
        <row>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </row>
       </xsl:for-each>
       <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      </result>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dvc-foldl-func:*" mode="f:FXSL">
         <xsl:param name="arg1"/>
         <xsl:param name="arg2"/>

         <xsl:variable name="vCurCount" select="count($arg1)"/>

         <xsl:variable name="vNewCount" select="count($arg2//text)"/>

         <xsl:variable name="vAvailable" select=
         "$pChunkSize - $vCurCount mod $pChunkSize"/>

         <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="$vNewCount le $vAvailable">
             <xsl:sequence select="$arg1, $arg2//text"/>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:sequence select="$arg1"/>
             <xsl:for-each select="1 to $vAvailable">
              <xsl:sequence select="$vPadding/*"/>
              </xsl:for-each>
              <xsl:sequence select="$arg2//text"/>
           </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct, wanted result is produced**:

```
<result>
   <row>abc</row>
   <row>def</row>
   <row>xxx</row>
   <row>yyy</row>
   <row>zzz</row>
   <row>abc2</row>
   <row>def2</row>
   <row/>
   <row>abc3</row>
   <row>def3</row>
   <row>xxx3</row>
   <row>yyy3</row>
   <row>zzz3</row>
   <row> </row>
   <row> </row>
   <row> </row>
</result>
```

**Do note**:

1. The use of the `f:foldl()` function.
2. A special DVC (Divide and Conquer) variant of `f:foldl()` so that recursion stack overflow is avoided for all practical purposes -- for example, the maximum recursion stack depth for 1000000 (1M) `trx` elements is just 19.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I'll double-check your first solution later (we're using XSLT 1.0) I feel confirmed, though, that tweaking XSL to make variables mutable in this one case isn't so bad after all... :-)

Comment: @LukasEder: XSLT is a functional language. This problem can be solved not only in XSLT but in any functional programming language -- probably in very similar ways. In most cases efficient functional solutions exist and can be used. I would greatly recommend reading a good book on functional programming -- one as "Haskell in the real world". Not only as general interest, but because in the coming XPath 3.0 / XSLT 3.0 and XQuery 3.0 functions are first-class-citizens (higher order functions) and functions like `fold-left()`, `fold-right()` and `map()` are standard in XPath 3.0.

Comment: @LukasEder: Also, you can read about functional (persistent) data structures (for example Kawasaki's book). A few years ago I implemented the Finger Tree data structure (in C#) and got amazing efficiencies for almost every possible operation compared to the existing (non-functional) collections in .NET. You can read more on this in my blog.

Answer (score 0):

As promised a simplified example answer showing how Xalan can be tweaked to allow for incrementing such global iterators:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:f="xalan://com.example.Functions">
  <!-- the global row counter variable -->
  <xsl:variable name="row" select="0"/>

  <xsl:template match="trx">
    <!-- wherever needed, the $row variable can be globally incremented -->
    <xsl:variable name="iteration" value="f:increment('row')"/>

    <!-- based upon this variable, calculations can be made -->
    <xsl:variable name="remaining-rows-in-chunk" 
                  value="40 - (($iteration - 1) mod 40) "/>
    <xsl:if test="count(.//text) &gt; $remaining-rows-in-chunk">
      <xsl:call-template name="empty-row">
        <xsl:with-param name="rows" select="$remaining-rows-in-chunk"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

    <!-- process transaction now, that previous chunk has been filled [...] -->
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="empty-row">
    <xsl:param name="rows"/>

    <xsl:if test="$rows &gt; 0">
      <row/>
      <xsl:variable name="dummy" select="f:increment('row')"/>

      <xsl:call-template name="empty-row">
        <xsl:with-param name="rows" select="$rows - 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the contents of `com.example.Functions`:

```java
public class Functions {
  public static String increment(ExpressionContext context, String nodeName) {
    XNumber n = null;

    try {
      // Access the $row variable
      n = ((XNumber) context.getVariableOrParam(new QName(nodeName)));

      // Make it "mutable" using this tweak. I feel horrible about
      // doing this, though ;-)
      Field m_val = XNumber.class.getDeclaredField("m_val");
      m_val.setAccessible(true);

      // Increment it
      m_val.setDouble(n, m_val.getDouble(n) + 1.0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Error", e);
    }

    return n == null ? null : n.str();
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: This solution will alter the state of the transformer. It cannot be reused afterwards, without manually resetting the variables at the beginning!